# How to optimize the maximum sum code so that I get tie<1.276s?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, sum, c++14

Given an array arr[] of N integers arranged in a circular fashion. Your task is to find the maximum continuous subarray sum.

Input:
First line of input contains a single integer T which denotes the number of test cases. First line of each test case contains a single integer N which denotes the total number of elements. Second line of each test case contains N space separated integers denoting the elements of the array.

Output:
For each test case print the maximum sum obtained by adding the consecutive elements.

I'm getting TLE.

Tried the key. Was earlier starting from index 0.

```
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> A;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        A.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        A.push_back(A[i]);
    }

    /*for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++){
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }*/
    int asum=0;
    int key=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        asum = asum + A[i];
        if(asum<0) key=i;
    }

    cout << key << "K" << endl;

    int max_sum = INT_MIN;

    for(int i=key; i<n; i++){
        int times = n;
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=i; times>0; j++){
            sum = sum + A[j];
            if(sum>max_sum) max_sum = sum;
            if(sum<0) sum=0;
            times--;
        }
    }

    cout << max_sum << endl;
```

TLE error. I checked for smaller cases. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? If not, that should be step 1. Step 0 would be thinking about reducing the algorithmic complexity of your solution. Step 2 would be running your (compiler optimized) code through a profiler, to identify bottlenecks.

Comment: What does it mean for N integers to be arranged in a circular fashion?

Comment: TLE usually means your algorithm is not optimal.

Comment: Explain the algorithm you coded. What does each loop do? What are you computing? Why?  The typical approach for that problem, in linear version, is to sum the values to the left of each value and to the right of it. Then get the best cutting points left and right of each. Then check the best combo of cutting points. All three can be done in linear time. Maybe this can be adapted to a circular buffer.

Comment: looks like you're having a nested for loop which means your algorithm is O(N²)

Answer (score 2):

The maximum subarray sum in a linear array is a classical problem that can be [solved in linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm).

Here we have a circular array, so we will split it into a linear array at an arbitrary point. Now the maximum subarray either will include the split point or it won't include the split point. In the latter case, the subarray will be a contiguous subarray in the rolled out linear array, so the answer can be computed using the aforementioned algorithm.

If the subarray includes the split point, it will correspond to a prefix of the rolled out array and a suffix not overlapping with the prefix. The sum of that is just the sum of the entire array minus the sum of the subarray in the middle. So you can just use the same algorithm to find the subarray with the minimum sum and subtract it from the total sum.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your algorithm. A better one could be: find the two sub-arrays at the beginning and end of A that have the minimal sum `sum_l` `sum_r`. That way, the remaining array's sum is `total - sum_l - sum_r`.

The thing is, those two minimal sub-arrays can be found in linear time. Scan first to find the running sum from the end. Scan again to find the best(minimal) running sum to the left and to the right. Save those. Scan again to find the minimal sum of best running sums.

That gives you the answer if the solution is not wrapping around. If the answer wraps around, you just need to maximize `sum_l` and `sum_r`. Compute both(wrapping or not) keep the best.

For example, with `A = {-5, 6, -2, -1, 8, -2};` you get:

sum_l -5, 1, -1, -2, 6, 4

sum_r 4, 9, 3, 5, 6, -2

Best_l -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5

Best_r -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -5

Total 4

Best combo: -7

Best result: 4-(-7) = 11

Which is 6-2-1+8

Comment: Not gonna work when circular will be taken in consideration like for
{8 -8 9 -9 10 -11 12}

Comment: You missed the "If the answer wraps around, you just need to maximize sum_l and sum_r" part. I actually coded it up and tested it. I'm not going to put the whole solution out for you, though. This answer is meant as guidance. :-)